# c# treeview allow selection of last child element only

Tags: c#, treeview, treenode

I have a treeview and I would like that the user will be able to select the last child only, in order to avoid problems when it is not selected an item, but a folder.

Has anybody any idea of if there exists such function for the treeview? I have not found it.

If there is not, a solution like checking if the last children has been selected or a directoy, I can try by myself. At this moment I would only know it that can be done setting any treeview feature.

Comment: Use that `tag` property of a `TreeNode`, so you can easily differentiate between folder, items, etc. Restricting a user from selecting certain tree nodes is unnecessary overhead.

Comment: I agree with @JohnWillemse

Answer (score 0):

It is not a `treeview` feature. But you can use the [Tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.tag.aspx) property which allows the node to keep an object with it. (In your case a good way to know what type it is).

As stated in the comments, maybe you should review your design (altough I have no idea why you need such a restriction) it seems to me that preventing the user to click on some `nodes` is a bad approach.

You can programatically test if it is the last element with many approach like :

- Declare `Treeview Before_Select Event`
- Test if `EventArgs e` has child nodes
- Allow or Cancel node select

Like I said this is one of many options.